# GMP on iOS using gmp4osx

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmp

I was wondering if anyone has ever worked with the gmp4osx [found here](https://github.com/ischlecken/gmp4osx) in order to create a framework for iOS. I had managed to get it up and running, about four months ago, but then accidentally deleted the folder and now when I follow the instructions to re-build it, I cannot get the `gmp-iPhoneOS.h` or `gmp-iPhoneSimulator.h` files in the `libgmp.framework` folder that is output by the procedure.

I remember that in the past, I just dragged and dropped the `libgmp.framework` folder in my project and imported the `gmp.h` file in my ViewController class and everything worked smoothly. The main goal of this file is to import the proper `gmp-*` file in the project, depending on the target OS. So in case of iPhone it will import the `gmp-iPhoneOS.h`. But this file does not exist on my hard drive!

If anyone could please point out a solution, I would really appreciate it! If not, just try to build it on your Mac and see if you get these files (might be a compiler error on my machine, or something else - that I doubt though, since I have tried on a clean installation as well).

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK got it working! If anyone wants GMP for iOS (or even OSX), just follow the steps below. The problem is that the build script is created for iOS 5.1 and today we need it working for 6.1! The answer was in the Issues tab of github. Can't believe I didn't see it coming!

So here it goes:

1. Download and extract the [gmp4osx project](https://github.com/ischlecken/gmp4osx)
2. Open up and edit `gmp4osx-master/libgmp/gmp4osx`
3. On line 19 it says `IOSVERSION=5.1`, change it to `IOSVERSION=6.1`
4. Save the file
5. Browse to that directory with terminal and type in `./gmp4osx -b`
6. Drag and drop the folder `gmp4osx-master/libgmp/build/libgmp.framework` in your project
7. Import the headers (sample code following) and you have GMP for any platform :)

If you don't know how to import the header files, simply copy and paste the following code and you will have it working!

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "libgmp/gmp.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mpz_t x;
    mpz_init_set_ui(x, 2);
    mpz_pow_ui(x, x, 5);
    gmp_printf("%Zd", x);
    //NSString *c;
    //mpz_get_str(&c, 10, x);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: hmmmm... followed your steps but i'm getting a "ld: framework not found libgmp" error during linking... any ideas?

Comment: When drag-and-drop the folder with the library (step 6) you are prompted to do some things. Did you try checking the "copy" checkbox and checking your project's target at the frame with the targets? Maybe that would fix it...

Comment: yeah, i did that. but i probably did something else stupid because after redownloading, rebuilding, and adding it to the project i've got it work now. sweet! thank you!

Comment: @TeoSartori did you find a way to get it working with GMP 6.1.0 ?

Comment: @Teo - I used your builder script for iOS but when I include the framework, I get build error for "gmp-iPhoneSimulator.h file not found". Same for the other header files in gmp.h.

Comment: @Jake have a look at my SwiftGMP project to see how to set up Xcode to use the libraries.

Comment: @Jake Can you verify it worked to edit the response with the new information?